# How to resize google recaptcha per the container size

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

[image]

Need to align the captcha in the container.

Code -

```
<div id="googleRecaptcha" class="">
    <div  class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="${siteKey}" data-callback="" data-expired-callback="">
    </div>
</div>
```

The right border of the captcha is not visible

It's looking different in 2 places:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **.g-recaptcha** class is given the transform: **scale(0.8);** property, which scales down the widget to 80% of its original size. The transform-origin: 0 0; property ensures that the scaling is applied from the top-left corner, maintaining alignment.

```
.g-recaptcha {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    transform-origin: 0 0; /* Set the origin to the top-left corner to maintain alignment */
}
```

Comment: Its looking different at 2 places as its coming on 2 places. I have attached the screenshots above. Please check

Comment: Exactly What do you really want, tell me the details